# Android Studio Emulator not loading

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I've tried multiple different emulator options and none of them seem to work. When I run my app, the emulator takes forever to even load, then after 10 minutes I'll just get a message like "System UI isn't responding" or something like that. What should I do to get my emulator to work?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to increase RAM amount in AVD settings.
2. Enable hardware graphics emulation.
3. If none of this helped, install [genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/).

https://jolicode.com/blog/speed-up-your-android-emulator

[Why is the Android emulator so slow? How can we speed up the Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/why-is-the-android-emulator-so-slow-how-can-we-speed-up-the-android-emulator)

Answer (score 0):

whats your system specs..
there is so many work around to this depending where your system spec faults
1st increase RAM & Paging file
2nd install HAXM if using intel laptops
3rd download intel images for emulator...works faster for intel systems

now in the AVD settings you do as above...